# Showing rows as columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have a `networks` table and a `groups` table and they are linked by each group being connected to a network.

Each group have a `type` and some of these groups are `special type` of groups.

I'm trying to run query that will display each group that is a a special type to be displayed as a column showing how many people are in that group type.

Is that something that is possible? Having each group type being displayed as a column header.

Data:

```
Networks

id | name
1  | networka
2  | networkb


groups

id | name   | type | network
1  | groupa | 1    | 1
2  | groupb | 2    | 2
3  | groupc | 3    | 1

type

id | name     | special
1  | speciala | 0
2  | specialb | 1
```

I currently running:

```
SELECT Name FROM (

    SELECT groups.Name FROM groups INNER JOIN group_types on groups.Type = group_types.Id WHERE group_types.SpecialType = 1 Group by groups.Type
) as s
```

which returns the list of groups with special type. But if I want to get more information such as the number of members in that group assuming I have a `group_members` table that links back to the `groups` table or the numbers of groups with that type.

I currently get two a row:

```
name
specialb
```

but I actually want to return back

```
specialb
(sub query to get more values for that special group)
```

Comment: the missing tag here is `pivot`. @Dani, you need to specify the schema of your table and sample records on it..

Comment: You may find this solution useful.

http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#78

Comment: sorry did not know about pivote, but it seems i actually don't need the data to show in a column format and instead it could be in a row format.  the different columns will just have to information in regard to that row.

Comment: i guess the question is how do i create dynamic columns where for every special type i can show a new column.  is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, write this:

```
select g.name, t.name, count(*)
from groups as g left join group_members as gm on gm.group=g.id left join types as t on t.id=g.type
group by g.name, t.name
```

then copy and paste into Excel using paste special > transpose.